# Hierarchical Query Trouble

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to do a Hierarchical query to select a "Center" and all his parent (up to 5 parent rows). For business reasons it has to be 6 rows, so if my center has only two parents I have to complete the table with my actual center.
I accomplished the first part with this:

```
SELECT centro as center, nodo as node , nodo_padre as father_node, 
level as Lvl
FROM BUP01.NODOTREE
where rownum < 7
START WITH NODO = 35250453 
CONNECT BY  NODO= PRIOR NODO_PADRE 
order by lvl desc
```

And get this:

```
|CENTER    | NODE                | FATHER_NODE         |        LVL|
|----------| --------------------| --------------------| ----------|
|000-101   | 1                   | 0                   |          3|
|000-102   | 25974018            | 1                   |          2|
|000-107   | 35250453            | 25974018            |          1|
```

But I need to perform a query that throw the next result:

```
|CENTER     |NODE                 |FATHER_NODE         |        LVL|
|---------- |-------------------- |--------------------| ----------|
|000-101    |1                    |0                   |          6|
|000-102    |25974018             |1                   |          5|
|000-107    |35250453             |25974018            |          4|
|000-107    |35250453             |25974018            |          3|
|000-107    |35250453             |25974018            |          2|
|000-107    |35250453             |25974018            |          1|
```

Comment: *Please* show example input data.

Comment: Why do you want/need that result? If you `START WITH NODO = 35250453' then you will get its row only at level 1. You get other levels if you do **not** `START WITH NODO = ...` but instead you run the hierarchy from every possible node, and retain just the rows that have that node. From the "desired result" it looks like this is not really a tree but rather a "bamboo stalk" (each parent has exactly one child). So - again - what problem are you trying to solve, where you think this will be part of the solution? Somehow this doesn't feel like a right approach to a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with t as
(
  SELECT          centro as center, nodo as node , nodo_padre as father_node, level as Lvl
  FROM            NODOTREE
  START WITH      NODO = 35250453 
  CONNECT BY      NODO = PRIOR NODO_PADRE
              and level <= 6
)

select          center,node,father_node,lvl+(6-count(*) over ()) as lvl

from            t

union all

select          center,node,father_node,level as lvl

from           (SELECT    centro as center, nodo as node , nodo_padre as father_node
                FROM      NODOTREE
                where     NODO = 35250453 
                      and 6 - (select count (*) from t) > 0
                )

connect by      level <= 6 - (select count (*) from t)

order by        lvl desc
;
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks so much!

Comment: @GonzaloBritez, since it answered your question, please mark it as a correct answer.